# Spring data neo4j LIKE query not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm new on neo4j spring data, and the query i'm trying to do its not working on my spring boot application, but working on the neo4j web interface.

I have 3 nodes on the database: "oracle", "java" and "cloud"
The query i'm trying to run:

```
MATCH(interest:Interest) WHERE interest.name =~ '(?i).*cl.*' RETURN interest
```

So, using the neo4j web interface, if i put "cl" it will return "oracle" and "cloud", which is correct.

Using spring data, i get all 3 results, which is wrong.

My repository interface:

```
@Query("MATCH(interest:Interest) WHERE interest.name =~ '(?i).*{0}.*' RETURN interest")
Set<Interest> getKindOf(String value);
```

My rest controller:

```
@ResponseBody
public Collection<Interest> getPersonByName(@PathVariable String name) {
    Set<Interest> interests = interestRepository.getKindOf(name);
    return interests;
}
```

Checking Spring boot logs i can see the query:

```
INFO 12716 --- [nio-2016-exec-1] o.n.o.drivers.http.request.HttpRequest   : Thread: 22, url: http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit, request: {"statements":[{"statement":"MATCH(interest:Interest) WHERE interest.name =~ '(?i).*{0}.*' RETURN interest","parameters":{"0":"cl"},"resultDataContents":["graph"],"includeStats":false}]}
```

So, the question is: Why i get 2 results using neo4j web interface (OK) and 3 results using spring data (NOK)?

Thanks for the help!

Rodrigo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The complete regex should be passed as argument (aka cypher query parameter)

```
@Query("MATCH(interest:Interest) WHERE interest.name =~ {0} RETURN interest")
Set<Interest> getKindOf(String value);
```

--

```
@ResponseBody
public Collection<Interest> getPersonByName(@PathVariable String name) {
    String regex = "(?i).*" + name + ".*";
    Set<Interest> interests = interestRepository.getKindOf(regex);
    return interests;
}
```

Note this has to do with the cypher parameters handling, this is not specific to sdn

Comment: Thanks a lot Christophe, looking at the logs now it makes sense. It's working now. Cheers!

Comment: The next version of Spring Data Neo4j will support additional derived finders, including `findPropertyByRegex`